# UIColor result in NSString problem?

Tags: iphone

NSString *st = [[UIColor greenColor] description]; 
it gives wrong output.
**i want to get the Result , st must be  @"greenColor" as a NSString**
any help please?

Answer (score 3):

`greenColor` is just the name of a class method on `UIColor`. Once the `UIColor` is constructed it doesn't know it's a `greenColor` - it just knows that it has colour values that happen to make green.

So I'd suggest one of two things.

1. Create a category on `UIColor` that intercepts `description` and compares the colour values against the set of colour constructors and return the appropriate string.
2. Subclass `UIColor` and store a colour name string. Supply a `description` method that just returns that string.

I suspect (2) is simpler but requires that you are able to use your subclassed version instead of `UIColor`.